# Wix Custom Action works under Windows 8, Fails under Windows 7

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm launching a custom action console application that can return 0 or -1.

On Windows 8 when it returns 0, the install continues.

On Windows 7 when it returns 0, the install ends prematurely.

```
<Property Id="QtExecCmdLine" Value="&quot;$(var.SourceFiles)\MyProgram.exe&quot;"/>
<CustomAction Id="CheckForOld" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="immediate" Return="check"/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
     <Custom Action="CheckForOld" After="AppSearch" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Does anyone know what can be done to resolve this?

Comment: I'd create a verbose log to see what's going on. It might even be possible that the code is crashing, and simply had the default exit code of zero and it's the crash that's causing the install to finish. Just speculation, but then I don't know how you are sure what the exit codes are.

Comment: I wrote the code.  It runs fine as a standalone program in both windows 7 and 8.

Comment: How does the exe file behave in a batch file? `filename.exe > log.txt 2>&1` (STDOUT, STDERR)

Comment: It works flawlessly in a batch file.  That is how I initially tested that the return code was operating correctly.

Comment: Steve, you're not running it as a user - it's a call from an msiexec process running with an irrelevant or unexpected working directory having been streamed out of the MSI file to some temporary location. In other words the fact that it works when you run it as interactive user is only a first sanity check. Code behaves very differently in other environments. And does your code have a dependency on something that may not been installed?

Comment: You are forgetting that IT RUNS under windows 8. So the suggestions and concerns listed don't seem to apply. I've isolated the problem down to one variable:  the operating system.  I've concluded that one of the two MSI engines has a bug.

Comment: One of the MSI engines has a bug?  Unlikely

Answer (score 2):

What are the [UAC levels/settings](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-user-account-control#1TC=windows-7) on the Windows 8 and Window 7 machines? If you have UAC disabled on your dev machine but enabled (default setting) on the test Win 7 you could get the EXE failing to run as a custom action.

In this case I also recommend migrating your code to a DLL, you could write a C# DLL, [using WixToolset and DTF](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2008/05/deployment-tools-foundation-dtf-custom.html).
The DLL can then set a property with the result of this search, and you can use that property to define a new [launch condition](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/launchconditions.html) to stop the installation, if required.

From [Tao of the Windows Installer, Part 5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2006/07/28/681358.aspx)

> **Rule 53: Test thoroughly**  It is crucial that you test your packages thoroughly before deployment. A classic mistake is for
>   developers and package authors to test only on their own systems where
>   they have full administrator rights and then discover that normal
>   users cannot use their applications.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion.   If I hadn't burned a lot of time on this I might try it.  But there are no guarantee this might not cause other problems.  Time to try another tool.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a QT exe file? What is the EXE file doing / checking? What happens if you turn off error checking - does it run and perform its task?

I wouldn't recommend to run a custom action with an exe file if you write the code yourself. Write it as a dll and connect the debugger to the code to step through it using a debug build dll - you will see exactly what happens as you step through the code:

- Insert code to show a message box from within the function you want to debug
- Compile a debug dll file and insert into the MSI file with the necessary plumbing to hook things up. This isn't entirely trivial, but not that complicated. See link below.
- Run the MSI and wait for the message box to show
- Attach the debugger to the correct msiexec.exe - either the user context one or the system context one depending on how your custom action is sequenced
- Set breakpoints and step through the code to determine what is happening

How to create a basic MSI dll:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1747/MSI-Custom-Action-DLL

Comment: It's looking in the registry for previously installed software.  I already know what the executable is doing.  It runs fine on both windows 7 and 8.  However, when called by Msiexe, under windows 7, it ignores the return value.

Comment: Even if you know the exe code, running as part of a setup is very different. Are you running in deferred or immediate mode? This has major security implications. Is it a QT exe file?

Comment: I tried running in both modes.  Both failed.  I don't know what a "QT exe file" is.   It is a .NET console app.

Answer (score 0):

What is this EXE supposed to do?  There are several code smells.  First is that it's scheduled in the UI sequence only.  It won't get run during a silent install.   The second is it's an EXE scheduled as immediate.  EXE's can't access the MSI handle and set properties or do anything useful so I assume the EXE is changing the configuration of the machine.  This is inappropriate outside of the execute sequence transaction.   Finally,  QtExecCmdLine needs an absolute path to the EXE on the destination machine.  I don't see how $(var.SourceFiles) could provide that.  That's a preprocessor variable that's only going to tell you where the file exists on the build server.

You aren't testing on your own dev machine?  I'm guessing you build this on a Win 8 box and then tested on the same box.  It happens to work cause it can find the file.  When you run it on another machine (Win 7)  it can't find the file and fails because the file can't possibly be there... you haven't installed anything yet.

Comment: The EXE looks in the registry for keys.  It returns 0 or -1 depending on if it finds the keys.  I do test on my development machine and then test on a Windows 7 machine.   $(var.SourceFiles) is where the installation files are.  I don't want to install the file, just run it to see if it's safe to continue the installation.   And on my machine it finds it.  And according to the log, it finds it on the test Windows 7 machine as well.  Good suggestions.  I'll try it on another Windows 8 machine as a sanity check.

Comment: You should NEVER test on your own machine. Installers 101: http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2007/08/hotfix-com-extraction-causes-system.html

Comment: I disagree with that blanket statement.  You should test on your own machine to validate the functionality is there....because it saves time.  When that is working, THEN test on another target machine.

Comment: @SteveWellens Seriously?  Good luck with that.  I'll keep doing my testing on snapshotted VM's. Expect no further help from me.

Comment: Clearly you are misunderstanding.  After you compile a program, do you run it?   Do you push a few buttons to see if it works?   Congratulations, you are testing on your own machine.  I'll try to bear up under the absence of your astute assistance.

Comment: There is a huge difference between compiling and debugging a program in an IDE and build and testing an installer on your own machine.  I'm not misunderstanding anything.  I've been writing installers for 18 years, blogging about installers for 11 years, 5000 posts on the InstallShield Community forum and the #1 contributor for all Windows Installer related tags here on StackOverflow.  Trust me... do not test installers on your dev box unless you can reset the snapshot on that also.  It will bight you and you'll be asking for help.  I've had to help many people at my day jobs and here.

Comment: You ARE misunderstanding.  I agree that final/acceptance should never be done on the developers box.  Of course not.  But you said NEVER test on a developers box. Certainly you run programs on your machine before you take then to the test machine.  That is testing.   PS:  I think you meant bite, not bight.  This is not a productive conversation.  I can tell you are someone who insists on the last word so knock yourself out.  Best wishes.